# How do I install the latex package wasysym on Mac? I just downloaded the zip file

Tags: packages, installing, mactex

I want to use this package on Pages to have a wider symbol range. I searched a lot online but nothing seems to work… can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your write-up isn't very clear at the present. Are you asking how to make the `wasysym` package work with the `Pages` wordprocessing program? If so, your query is off-topic for this site, and you may have more luck if you repost the question on https://apple.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Why don't you install it via TeX Live Utility?

Comment: @Mico oh thanks! I'll try that now!

Comment: @Bernard because I'm a complete beginner and I don't know how to do that (or pretty much anything else in this field...)